# opennlp: How to get word frequency

Tags: java, nlp, opennlp

If I use opennlp in JAVA, how can I get the frequency of every token in a txt file? I try to use `tokenizer.getTokenProbabilities()`, but it seems not for word frequency but for probabilities. Any method recommend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found [this](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-get-word-frequency-in-opennlp) from a google search. Looks good enough.
Is this what you were looking for?